# bind("tcp://*:6001") meaning in python

Tags: python, ipc, zeromq

I came across a zeromq example code

```
subscriber = ctx.socket(zmq.XSUB)
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:6000")

publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.XPUB)
publisher.bind("tcp://*:6001")
```

The subscriber (client) is connecting to `local host` port 6000. But the publisher (the server) is binding to `*:6001`

What does this mean?

Comment: Its the same as `0.0.0.0`, which means _all addresses_

Comment: n.b.: the below explained meaning is not specific to python, but rather **specific to a way, how ZeroMQ internally parses the syntax with a wildcard directive** for <_IP_Address_> part of **`.bind()`** request `{ <_aTcpIpTransportCLASS_> "://" { <_IP_Address_> | "*" } ":" <_Port#_> }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "all interfaces, port 6001" - a given computer can have more than one network interface (a trivial example would be that the average computer's LAN IP and it's localhost address are two different interfaces. The `*` means to accept connections from any of them.

Answer (score 1):

### What does it mean to `.bind()` at port 6000 while `.connect()` aims at port 6001?

Simply put, **these two peers will not meet** at this attempt to setup a link to communicate.

While wildcard does work for all <*localhost*> interfaces, **it does not** for `port`#-s.

A `.bind()` side can open it's receiving policy to accept a connection from ***any*** interface "behind" the **`*`** wild card, but **the** `port`#-s **must match**.

*No exceptions, no excuse.*

Comment: ... however, this could be intended if this is a message broker, where the subscriber is connecting to a publisher on a different host, and the publisher is binding to send to subscribers on different hosts... but with a simplistic example like this, it *does* look like they are intended to communicate to each other.

Comment: :o) a fair notice Jason, however the O/P context seemed exactly as you've noted. I've brought my cent just due to the fact, the accepted answer did not touch the O/P question ( in the last row ), while it did help better understand the wildcard-syntax feature for the .bind()-side to BIND & watch all <_localhost_> interfaces